Understanding the difference between df and $| \triangledown f|$
I am seeking some clarification regarding a couple of vector calculus topics. Let's suppose z = f(x,y) is a surface in $\mathbb{R}^3$, and for the sake of having something to hold onto that z represents money we make based on x (number of workers) and y (products we sell).
As I understand it, $df = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}dx + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}dy$. This represents the total differential of f(x,y). What I thought this represented was if I'm at some point on the surface $(x_o, y_o, z_o)$, then I could somehow figure out the amount z would change if we modified our $x_o$ and $y_o$ a tiny bit. To be more precise with my thinking, since $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$ represent the particular change in z we would experience if we wandered off a tiny bit in the x or y direction respectively, if we scale each rate by dx and dy respectively (our tiny bit of wandering) and add the results, we get the total change in z we would experience (df).
Now we have this thing called the gradient which consists of $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$, specifically $\triangledown f = <\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$, $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}>$. And to top it off, the idea is that this is a vector that lies on the x-y plane and points in the direction of steepest ascent. Suppose the gradient at a particular point was $<4, 3>$, I have been taking this to mean that if we increase the number of workers by 4 and the number of units sold by 3, then we will increase our revenue the quickest possible AND we would expect to make \$5 more as a result, since $|\triangledown f| = 5$.
So my questions are as follows:

Is my intuition correct for both concepts?

In what (simple) scenarios would I want to use the result of df vs. the result of $|\triangledown f|$ when talking about what to expect to happen to the z-values of my surface? I'm having trouble putting into words the lack of ability I'm having differentiating between the two concepts and uses. Not to mention that if df measures change in z based on the change in the x and y direction, but $|\triangledown f|$ also measures the change but then says it's the maximum change...I'm just a bit confused.



They're pretty much the same thing. The gradient of $f$ is a vector field pointing in the direction of maximum increase.

We usually write
$$\nabla f = \frac{df}{dx}i + \frac{df}{dy}j$$
to denote this vector field. The differential of $f$, is essentailly the same thing.
$$df = \frac{df}{dx}dx + \frac{df}{dy}dy.$$
The way you think about this object is that it's a combination of a $dx$ part and a $dy$ part. A small change in $f$ is $\frac{df}{dx}$ in the $dx$ direction plus $\frac{df}{dy}$ in the $dy$ direction.
In some sense, it's a small change in $f$. And it somehow represents the same idea as the gradient.
If you take a course in manifolds, you learn that these objects pretty much turn out to mean the same thing.

But the magnitude of the gradient gives a very different result for the expected change in z, versus the differential. So where is the difference between them coming from?

@TheMathPotato what does it mean to you when you say take the maginute of $df$?

To me that question doesn't make sense, because you evaluate df at a point, based on some provided small change in x and y. That is, you'll have a value for dx, dy, df/dx, and df/dy, and they combine to give you df, which is our prediction of the change in f (compared to the actual change in f which can be gotten by just evaluating the new z-value and comparing it to our old one). So I'm not sure what "magnitude of df" means. But I'm more interested in the magnitude of the gradient vector at that point and how it compares to df.

I think something just clicked though. df is the expected change in our z-value depending on which direction we go in (indicated by the dx and dy that scale against our df/dx and df/dy). The gradient vector identifies the precise direction to head in to maximize the value of df. Where I'm still getting caught up though is that the magnitude of the gradient is sqrt[(df/dx)^2 + (df/dy)^2], whereas df = (df/dx)dx + (df/dy)dy. How does the magnitude of the gradient give us change in z, but df is supposed to be change in z?

For an arbitrary tangent vector $v$, by definition of the gradient, $\langle v, \nabla f\rangle = df(v)$. So $df(v) = |v||\nabla f|\cos \theta$.

Would you mind checking out my follow-up post to this and clarifying the question for me? :)
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4920935/understanding-the-difference-between-df-and-triangledown-f-part-2

@TheMathPotato Ok I precisely and rigorously gave the relationship between $df$ and $\nabla f$ in my answer there :)

@TheMathPotato you had some errors in your reasoning that I illustrated. Think of $df$ as a directional derivative that eats tangent vectors rooted at a point and spits out a number. It's related to the gradient by the inner product.

@TheMathPotato This is technical and something you don't see until later in a math degree: but in some sense the $df$ is "dual" to the $\nabla f$ and this duality is realized by the inner product or more generally the Riemannian metric.

The gradient is the vector of partial derivatives $\nabla z = [\frac{\partial z}{\partial{x}}\,\,\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}]^T$, while the total differential (not the total derivative) is $dz = \frac{\partial z}{\partial x}dx + \frac{\partial z}{\partial y}dy$ which can be also expressed by the gradient $dz = \nabla z \,\cdot\, [dx\,\,dy]^T$. One application of the total differential is the chain rule in integration, while gradients are important for example when we want to study the rate of change of the function $f(x,y)$ non-uniformly along the coordinates (like in mathematical optimization).
You calculate the partial derivative of $f(x,y)$ with respect to one variable while keeping the others constant, while for the total derivative you allow all the variables to vary at once. An example from here:
$$
f(x,y(x)) = x^2 + y ,\quad y(x) = x+2 .
$$
Then the partial derivative $\partial f/\partial x$ ignores the dependence of $y$ on $x$ and outputs $\partial f / \partial x = 2x$, while the total derivative takes it into account resulting $df/dx = 2x + 1$.
