Understanding the difference between df and $| \triangledown f|$ (part 2)
Suppose we have the 3-D surface $f(x,y) = xy^2$ and the point (2, 3, 18).
Then $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}= y^2$, and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}= 2xy$, and so $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(2,3)= 9$ and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(2,3)= 12$.
Therefore the total differential at that point $df = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}dx + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}dy$ can be calculated as $df(2,3) = 9dx + 12dy$. As I understand it, this would give me the expected change in my z-value if I were to go to some new point dx and dy away--namely $(2 + dx, 3 + dy, z)$.
Now, the gradient $\triangledown f = <\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}, \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}>$, and so $\triangledown f(2,3) = <9, 12>$. Here's where things get fuzzy for me:
According to the formula $df = 9dx + 12dy$, if I were to walk +9 in the x-direction (making dx = 9) and walk +12 in the y-direction (making dy = 12)--indicating I moved to the point (11, 15, z)--then we'd get $df= 9(9) + 12(12) = 225$ and thus we'd expect to be at the point (11, 15, 243), since this is the same as (2 + 9, 3 + 12, 18 + 225).
On the other hand, what I understand the gradient vector $<9, 12>$ to represent is the exact direction we need to go in to experience the most amount of change. Since $|\triangledown f(2,3)| = |<9, 12>| = \sqrt{9^2 + 12^2} = 15$, this would indicate that if I start at the point (2, 3, 18) and walk +9 in the x-direction and +12 in the y-direction, then I would expect to experience a change in z of + 15 (and that this would be the largest such change in z I could possible experience, given all the directions I could have gone from the point I started at).
But that would make my df = 15, not equal to 225 like the formula for df suggests.
So where is my misunderstanding?

Suppose $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}$. Ok let's view $df$ as the directional derivative of $f$. It eats a vector $v\in \mathbb{R}^n$ and spits out a number. By definition of the directional derivative,
$$d_vf = \langle v, \nabla f\rangle.$$
Now we can ask, when is $d_vf$ maximized among all unit vectors? Fix a unit vector $v$ so that $\|v\|=1$.
$$ d_vf = \langle v, \nabla f\rangle = \|v\|\|\nabla f\|\cos \theta = \|\nabla f\|\cos \theta. $$
Now $-1\leq \cos \theta \leq 1$ and when $\theta=0$ $\cos\theta = 1$  so we see that $d_vf$ is maximized when the vector $v$ points in the direction of the gradient.
This is precisely the relationship between $\nabla f$ and $df$.

Ok I see where you are going wrong. You correctly calculated that $$\nabla f = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} i + \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}j= y^2i + 2xyj.$$
So at the point $2, 3$ we have
$$\nabla f = 9i + 12j.$$
Now at the point $2,3$ $df = 9dx + 12dy$.
And we are done. If we interpret $df$ as a directional derivative, then fixing a tangent vector rooted at $2,3$, we have $$df\left(\left[\begin{array}{l}
a \\
b
\end{array}\right]\right) = 9a + 12b.$$
Also you need to get rid of the $z$ coordinate. The gradient lives in $\mathbb{R}^2$ since you have a function of $x$ and $y$ and you don't have a 3d surface you have a 2d surface.

I'm following my textbook where they plug in values for dx and dy and get actual, numerical answers for df (they use dz) and then they compare it to the real $\Delta z$, which they get by subtracting the new z-value from the old z-value.
The textbook is Calculus, Early Transcendentals, 8th edition, Stewart. Page 933.

IT JUST CLICKED. So, moving +9 in the x-direction and +12 in the y-direction can be represented by the vector <9, 12>, which is $\triangledown f$ at the point (2,3). This vector has a length of 15. The length of 15 is representative of the rate of change if I walk in the direction of <9, 12>. But it's a RATE, which means to get the actual change in f, I would need to scale it by however far I walk in that direction!!! Ever 1 unit I step in that direction gives me +15 in the z-direction. So walking 15 units in that direction gives me 15*15 = 225, which is df(2,3) for my dx = +9 and dy = +12!!!!

And BOOM goes the dynamite.

Also, what z-coordinate are you referring to that I should get rid of? $f(x,y) = xy^2$ is definitely a 3D surface, and I don't have any z-values in my gradient vectors.

Ok great! Good job. I don't think of $dx$ and $dy$ in this detail. I just think of them as a small change in x and a small change in y and $df$ as the linearization of $f$ at a point.

@TheMathPotato The surface is a 2d surface immersed in a 3d space.

I'm still confused. If you plug in an x-value and a y-value, you get a z-value, which makes it a 3D surface...unless you know something about what makes something 3D that I don't?

@TheMathPotato imagine you’re a particle traveling along the surface. You can only go in two directions.

I think maybe we're talking about two different things. You're talking about the gradient, which is a bunch of vectors that lie on the x-y plane, and I'm talking about my surface, which is the 3D equation $z = xy^2$ which lives in $\mathbb{R}^3$, making it 3D...

@TheMathPotato Sure. But it is still a 2d surface in a 3d space. There are only two degrees of freedom. $x$ direction and $y$ direction.

Maybe I'm the one getting lost in semantics. You're saying that a sphere isn't a 3D-object because it only has two degrees of freedom? What would make it "3D" then?

The ball ${x^2+y^2+z^2 \leq 1}$ is a 3-dimensional manifold with boundary. The sphere ${x^2+y^2+z^2 = 1}$ is a 2-dimensional manifold with boundary. In the first case, the tangent space at every point is 3-dimensional. In the sphere case, the tangent space is a 2-dimensional vector space so the manifold is 2d.

So if I hand a tennis ball to someone, am I handing them a 2D or a 3D object? Or is this only specific to math?

Its a formal math definition
